# Android chat library

Tags: android, library, chat

Is there a library for showing a chat on Android?

**Required features:**

- only the GUI part of the chat-feature
- overview over all chats
- a chat, something like [WhatsApp](http://scr.wfcdn.de/8415/WhatsApp-fuer-Android-mit-Holo-Design-1360843612-0-0.jpg) is showing.
- should not conflict with material design too much
- managed in Views and/or Fragments, not entire Activities (used in [Navigation Drawer](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html))
- binding via some customizable adapter

**Features that would be nice to have:**

- free
- open source/GitHub
- archiving chats
- emoticons

**Not needed:**

- support pre API level 14
- other message types than text (no audios, images, locations, ...)
- group chats